# Shopify adding two products to cart with one checkout button

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid, checkout

So I have a bundle I created to add two products to cart once those products are selected. I want them to be added to cart at the same time. I'm currently only getting one product being added, with the name="id". How can I create the values in input for both to checkout?

Here's my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add" class="col-button ">
                    <input id="idPrice" type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
                    <input id="designPrice" type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
                    <input min="1" max="2" type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
                      <button name="checkout"  {%unless product.available %}style='margin-bottom:20px;'{% endunless %}type="{% if settings.cart_action == 'ajax' %}button{% else %}submit{% endif %}" name="add" class="collection-add-to-cart {% if settings.cart_action == 'ajax' %} ajax-submit {% endif %}action_button add_to_cart {% if show_payment_button %} action_button--secondary {% endif %} {% if product.available == false %}disabled{% endif %}" data-label={{ add_to_cart_label | json }}>
                        {{ 'layout.general.checkout' | t }}
                      </button>
                 </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to check AJAX API to add more than one product into the cart.

Comment: Here is the link to [Shopify cart AJAX API](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart)